# Perfomance issue (Nginx, NodeJs, Mysql)

Tags: mysql, node.js, performance, nginx, performance-testing

I have the following problem.
Using REST, I am getting binary content (BLOBs) from a MySql database via a NodeJS Express app.
All works fine, but I am having issues scaling the solution.

I increased the number of NodeJS instances to 3 : they are running ports 4000,4001,4002.
On the same machine I have Nginx installed and configured to do a load balancing between my 3 instances.
I am using Apache Bench to do some perf testing.
Please see attached pic.

[image: Perf testing]

Assuming I have a dummy GET REST that goes to the db, reads the blob (roughly 600KB in size) and returns it back (all http), I am making 300 simultaneous calls. I would have thought that using nginx to distribute the requests would make it faster, but it does not.
[image]

Why is this happening? 
I am assuming it has to do with MySql? 
My NodeJs app is using a connection pool with a limit set to 100 connections. What should be the relation between this value and the max connection value in Mysql? If I increase the connection pool to a higher number of connections, I get worse results.

Any suggestion on how to scale?

Thanks!

Comment: How much CPU cores do you have on this machine? Do you run MySQL on the same box?

Comment: i7-6700, 4 cores : this server host the nodeJS apps (3) + nginx. MySQL server is on different box.

Comment: I was however able to improve the query - now I am able to see some improvements. ~600 requests were completed in ~90s (with a direct call to one to NodeJs). If I go via nginx (with 3 NodeJs apps), ~600 requests are completed in ~60s. So, it looks better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"300 simultaneous" is folly.  No one (today) has the resources to effectively do more than a few dozen of anything.

- 4 CPU cores -- If you go much beyond 4 threads, they will be stumbling over each over trying to get CPU time.
- 1 network -- Have you check to see whether your big blobs are using all the bandwidth, thereby being the bottleneck?
- 1 I/O channel -- Again, lots of data could be filling up the pathway to disk.

(This math is not quite right, but it makes a point...)  You cannot *effectively* run any faster than what you can get from 4+1+1 "simultaneous" connections.  (In reality, you may be able to, but not 300!)

The typical benchmarks try to find how many "connections" (or whatever) leads to the system keeling over.  Those hard-to-read screenshots say about 7 *per second* is the limit.

I also quibble with the word "simultaneous".  The only thing close to "simultaneous" (in your system) is the ability to use 4 cores "simultaneously".  Every other metric involves sharing of resources.  Based on what you say, ...

- If you start about 7 each second, some resource will be topped out, but each request will be fast (perhaps less than a second)
- If you start 300 all at once, they will stumble over each other, some of them taking perhaps *minutes* to finish.

There are two interesting metrics:

- How many *per second* you can *sustain*.  (Perhaps 7/sec)
- How long the average (and, perhaps, the 95% percentile) takes.

Try 10 "simultaneous" connections and report back.  Try 7.  Try some other small numbers like those.